# Excel: how to add a value to a cash flow projection every nth year

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am writing a cash flow projection for a business. There are a few recurring costs (such as licenses), which need to be repeated at different intervals. e.g. Some licences/costs recur annually, whereas some only need to be renewed every three years.

I know what the costs are, when they first occur, and how often they occur (in years). What I'm struggling to work out is an efficient way to transfer these costs to the cash flow projection. For example, if I have the three costs below in my 'costs sheet':

[image]

... Then I would expect the 'cash flow projection' sheet to look like this:

[image]

However, I cannot work out how to have Excel fill in the cash flow projection automatically. For one-off costs, I would use `SUMIF()` to find all costs matching the year. And for *annually* recurring costs, I would also use `SUMIF()` to check that the year is *greater than* the year that the costs starts. But in the case of recurring costs *that are not necessarily annual*, `SUMIF()` cannot achieve this.

Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Comment: Hi @CaptainProg,, using current data Copy year start & cost and TRANSPOSE,,, u get expected cash flow,, or another is calculation,, create a 2 columns Lookup table Year & next Cost and use Index match for expected output .

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh; I'm not sure I understand your suggestion? Transposing is just a copy-paste operation; not a formulaic way of automatically calculating anything. Your suggestion doesn't take into account the recurring years, which is the issue I am trying to address. And `INDEX()` / `MATCH()` can only look up specific values; here I am looking to find specific years (probably by using `MOD()` from the start year, where the divisor is the value in "recur every X years"). Could you elaborate by posting an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT and MOD:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MOD(F1,$C$2:$C$4)=MOD($A$2:$A$4,$C$2:$C$4))*($B$2:$B$4))
```

The mod test if the year is in the pattern and returns the value if it is to the sumproduct.

[image]